# "Nothing could be further from the truth"?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

Is there a French phrase that would be equivalent to the English "nothing could be further from the truth"? I want to say that something is completely untrue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal translation works here : "Rien n'est plus éloigné de la vérité"

Answer (score 1):

The French can be  more blunt in expressing themselves and  short  forms are a possible way to achieve this; the present case calls, as I see it, for just such a form.

« Ceci est faux » would probably be the closest.

Comment: Nah, that just means it's untrue. I want something stronger than that...

Comment: I appreciate but respectfully I disagree. It is bearing more weight than untrue

Answer (score 0):

All of the three sentences below have about the same force and are a good renderings.

- Il n'y rien de moins vrai.
- Il n'y a rien de plus faux.
- Rien n'est plus invraisemblable.

There are other possibilities;

- C'est de l'absurdité la plus complète. (*In cases when what is false is at the same time seen as blatantly illogical.*)